# Strange alignment of the menu from responsive to normal

Tags: css, responsive

sorry for the title...but I have an issue with the alignment of the main menu when the website come from responsive to pc view. (for example it happen when you rotate your tablet from portrait to landscape, or simply you enlarge your browser window from 600pixel wide to 1300px... ).

To understand what I mean just do this (just look at the main menu):

- open my website: http://www.piedicosta.com/joomla3/en
- reduce browser windows at 500/600 pixel wide, to let the css transform the website in responsive.
- open a submenu by clicking on the down arrow at right. Leave the sub menu open.
- now enlarge the browser window to let the css transform the website in pc view.

Can you see that the main menu, now float at left?

If you refresh the page, than the main menu comes at center.

This issue happen only if you leave (from responsive view) a submenu item open. If you don't touch the menu in responsive view nothing happen and everything seems working fine.

Is there a simple reason of this issue?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in your `responsive.css?reload` file.

On line 25:

```
#tm:checked + .main-menu {
/*display: inline-block;*/
display: block;<-- this guy is the problem-->
}
```

Change it to:

```
#tm:checked + .main-menu {
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

You can fix for your next problem via [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Now to be honest I am **not** sure which file you should edit, i think it should be `responsive.css?reload`. **Note:** Add CSS media code **after**

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
   ul.main-menu li a {
   padding: 27px 10px 10px;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    ul.main-menu li a {
    padding: 13px 17px 10px;
   }
}
/*Add code below HERE!!*/
```

Copy all the code below to your file:

```
/*
* - Mobile
*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {/* Serve big tablet layout and tablet menu kindle's and hi-res devices ( portrait ) */
    #tm:checked + .main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
     #toggle-menu .drop-icon, #menu li label.drop-icon {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {/* Tablets layout*/
    #tm:checked + .main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
    #toggle-menu .drop-icon, #menu li label.drop-icon {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {/* Small mobile devices */
 #tm:checked + .main-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
    #toggle-menu .drop-icon, #menu li label.drop-icon {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I think that your current menu configuration can't support what are you asking (didnt't figure out how to make your text align to left without messing something up, but maybe I am wrong) i did however make your arrow dropdown shifted to the right.

Comment: Thank you Dejo Dekic! You did the trick!!!!
I modified this instruction, just because I am not able to enlarge at 100% width the menu items when responsive...
Maybe do you know how to do it avoiding the strange behaviour you have solved?
Thanks a lot again!!!

Comment: Glad to help buddy... Not sure I understand what's your problem now. Can you elaborate or ask another question? Anyway I noticed that you haven't [Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) any answer on your questions. Be nice and accept any answer you find useful, it helps you (increasing Your reputation), me (increasing My reputation) and other people (maybe they have a similar problem). Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Dejo, I think I have now accepted your answer. Sorry I didn't do it before but I didn't understand how to do it.
Concerning my problem, I thank you again for solving my first issue.

What I want to do now is that:

- shrink your browser window until the menu became responsive.

Comment: Thank you Dejo, I think I have now accepted your answer
I thank you again for solving my first issue.

What I want to do now is that:

- shrink your browser window until the menu became responsive.

As you can see the text of the menu items ("welcome", "getting there", and so on...) are aligned centered together with the down arrow that you can see at right of the text...

Now I would like to have the text aligned left and the down arrow floated at right. Do you this is possible in a simply way?

I hope I have been more clear, now... Thank you so much for your kind help and support!

Comment: Sorry for the delay been busy... I have edited my answer hope it helps.

Comment: Great Dejo! Thank you so much!

I have edited like follow and it works:

    #tm:checked + .main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    }
     #toggle-menu .drop-icon, #menu li label.drop-icon {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }

The only thing it seems that re-appear the first issue...if I set width:100%, just because I need the menu item in full width when displays are less than 979px.

Comment: Try to add the code I provided to you, issue appears again because you haven't added media queries, copy all the code (@media only screen part) and change min-width to 100% and REMOVE #tm:checked + .main-menu {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: Thank you Dejo, I applied your last code, but I still continue to get these results: 
If you leave like this http://www.piedicosta.com/resp1.jpg
than you get this http://www.piedicosta.com/resp2.jpg

I just use only one instruction for mediaqueries because I need only respondive for screen less than 979px...